# Adding custom words to the tokenizer in scispacy

Tags: nlp, spacy, tokenize, named-entity-recognition

The tokens that I am dealing are biomedical terms, which are not tokenized properly by my spacy Named-Entity-Recognition(NER) model, words that are supposed to be together are divided abruptly. Clearly, this tokenizer is not ideal for my use case.
Now, I have a corpus of words/tokens extracted from different sources hoping they would improve the tokenizer performance and in turn the NER performance.

How to modify the tokenizer so that these words will be given more priority during the tokenization?  How to include this corpus into my vocab and How can I fine-tune a pre-trained model using the modified vocab for Named Entity Recognition Task?

Answer (score 0):

Consider implementing a custom tokenizer

```
import spacy

# Create a custom tokenizer
class CustomTokenizer:
    def __init__(self, vocab):
        self.vocab = vocab

    def __call__(self, text):
        words = text.split()  
        spaces = [True] * len(words)
        return spacy.tokens.Doc(self.vocab, words=words, spaces=spaces)

# Load a pre-trained spaCy model
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

# Add your biomedical terms to the vocabulary
biomedical_corpus = ["term1", "term2", "term3"]
for term in biomedical_corpus:
    nlp.vocab[term]

# Set the custom tokenizer
nlp.tokenizer = CustomTokenizer(nlp.vocab)

# You need to fine-tune the model as per your requirement.


# Test your modified tokenizer and NER model
text = "Biomedical term1 and term2 should be kept together."
doc = nlp(text)
for ent in doc.ents:
    print(ent.text, ent.label_)
```

Assuming you have limited no. of custom words